# URL Rewrite isn't working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite to write more user friendly URLS for my site.
I copied and modified a working rule for another page, but it doesn't seem to want to work...

Here's the rule

```
RewriteRule ^list/(.*)/page/([0-9])/$ list.php?date=$1&page=$2
```

The working rule lookst like this

```
RewriteRule ^read/(.+)/$ read.php?target=$1
```

As far as I can see, the new rule should work...
If anyone can suggest why it doesn't and possibly provide a fix, I'd greatly appreciate it

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Your rule will only work if the second parameter is between 0 - 9(aka. 1 digit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boy do I feel like an idiot now...

I had a look at this again this morning when I got in to work and found that there actually wasn't anything wrong with the rule. I hadn't changed my links...

For anyone referencing this, experiencing similar problems:
If you write a RewriteRule like I have above, make sure you change your link `href` attributes to use the new URL

So, in my case...

```
RewriteRule ^list/(.*)/page/([0-9]+)/$ list.php?date=$1&page=$2
```

The links have to change from

```
<a href="list.php?date=2012April&page=1>April 2012</a>
```

To

```
<a href="/list/2012April/page/1/
```

I forgot to change the links **derp**

Answer (score 1):

if your page number can have multiple digits, that part of the expression should be ([0-9]+) to require 1 or more digits.

Comment: Also note that with your rewriterule you need to add the / at the end of the date or the page will not work. You can find how to automatically add it when it's missing [in this website](http://www.mydigitallife.info/add-trailing-slash-to-the-end-of-the-url-with-htaccess-rewrite-rules/).

Comment: Thanks for this, I hadn't considered what might happen when I get to 10+ pages... The rule still doesn't work though